# Learning about quaternion

Tags: reference-request, quaternions, learning

I am looking to PDF/sites to be introduced into the concept of **quaternion** at **high-school level math**.
Thanks!

Comment: You might have seen this already, but Numberphile had made a video about it: https://youtu.be/3BR8tK-LuB0 .

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of articles on quaternions here:

[does-anyone-know-any-resources-for-quaternions-for-truly-understanding-them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331021/does-anyone-know-any-resources-for-quaternions-for-truly-understanding-them)

Some of them are too advanced for a high school student, but you will be able to find a few that should suit your needs.